# Change the class of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with 8 columns and 40 rows. All columns have numeric values. I need to change column 1 to 5 to character. I tried `dplyr::mutate_at()` but I cannot get it to work. I don't want to create new columns, but change the class of the existing ones. I keep getting the error 
*Column `col1` must be length 40 (the number of rows) or one, not 0*

What is the right way to do this with dplyr?
I guess I could just do

`df$col1 <- as.character(df$col1)`

for each of the columns, but I would like to learn the power of dplyr.

Any help is always appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: "I tried `dplyr::mutate_at()` but I cannot get it to work". Can you post the code you tried that didn't work? Also, please provide the dataframe by copy and pasting the output of `dput(mydata)` into your question.

Comment: Try `df[1:5] <- lapply(df[1:5], as.character)`

Answer (score 5):

Try doing it the way below:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0, 0), b = c(1, 1, 1), c = c(0, 0, 1), d = c(1, 1, 1), e = c(0, 0, 0))

df_updated <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(1:5), as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the duplicate. The problem was I was doing `mutate_at(vars(1:5), funs(as.character())